# Configuring S32K148 Microcontroller 144pins LQFP pin no 113(PTA1) as pull down

Tags: microcontroller, adc, current-measurement, pulldown, nxp

I am using [S32K](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) for current measurement purpose.

Using pin no 113 as ADC input.

I can see in the datasheet that ,we can configure this pin as pull down or pullup.

[image]

May I know is this possible to set this pull down value of 40K so that I can avoid the sense resistor at the output of the uC.

My maximum current is 112.36uA.

Below is my measurement circuit.

[image]

The calculated value of RSENSE is 40K.If I can set the pull down resistor as 40K,I will be

able to avoid putting a resistor outside.

In the datasheet gave the pull down range.No information how to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a 40k resistance, then put a 40k resistor.

There is no way to set the pull resistor value, it is due to manufacture.

The resistance will range is from 20k to 50k, whatever it happens to be.

If it even is a resistance. In some MCUs it will be an actual resistance switched by FETs. In some MCUs it will just be a weak FET.

Comment: Justme - Hi, If anyone is interested, although it's on a different MCU, [this post from NXP](https://community.nxp.com/t5/S12-MagniV-Microcontrollers/what-s-the-value-of-pull-up-and-pull-down-resistor-about/m-p/686782) explains more about the use of a FET which you mention, to implement the pull-up/down functionality.